# Getting image url from json is better or using an encoded image within json?

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a json from server in which the image urls are send from server but i want to know if i ask my php developer person to send encoded image in json would be a better approch or the former one ?
I want to load the images in listview after that.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The answer is "it depends". This affects the basic trade-off between latency and bandwidth. When you use URL's, you may suffer more from the former, if you use embedded data, you will be more affected by the latter. Which choice gives the better UX is dependent on the size and possible reuse of the images that you may embed, what phones your users have and what network plans they're on, whether you're using HTTP/2 and a bunch of other stuff. Secondary effects are battery life and data usage; embedding harms your ability to cache images on the client. My advice is keep it simple and send URLs.

Comment: Use OkHttp and a library like Volley or Picasso to get most of the caching and network optimization stuff for free. If nothing else, this will save you a lot of development time. These are good libraries from skilled authors.

Comment: Hi Barend i understood what you said Thanks but the client have problems with internet connection at his side so would it be useful to use the Urls there too

Answer (score 0):

getting url will be better and clean approach.it will make your response compact and image url can be loaded any time you want where if you transmit encoded image it has to be transmitted in network even if you dont want to display at the time.

Comment: Hi Kirtan i wanted to ask that if i fetch image through url  does i have to get the image in encoded format or i can access it directly from the url?